# What is the difference between "import package" versus "from package import ..."?

Tags: python, import, package

Why are some packages such as Pandas always imported as:

```
import <name of package> #e.g. import pandas as pd
```

While other packages are "imported" as:

```
from <name of package> import <module> #e.g. from fredapi import Fred
```

I understand that when you want to import packages that have a lot of modules, you can import a specific module you need with

```
from <name of package> import <module> #e.g. from fredapi import Fred
```

versus importing the entire package and all it's modules.

My question is more about the packages that are only able to imported with:

```
from <name of package> import <module> #e.g. from fredapi import Fred
```

Is it because of the structure of the package? Is it because it's not actually a package? I'm confusing myself at this point. Hope someone could shed some light on this.

A concrete example, I can never import fredapi like this:

```
import fredapi
```

I can only use fredapi with the "from" command.

```
from fredapi import Fred
```

Comment: "My question is more about the packages that are only able to imported with: `from <name of package> import <module>`"—are you sure that's the only way it can be imported? You can't do `import fredapi` followed by `fredapi.Fred.whatever()`?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a package as representing a bookshelf containing some books that you would like to read.

You could either choose to read everything at once:

```
import bookshelf
# read bookshelf.book1, bookshelf.book2, until bookshelf.bookN
```

Or you could pick a couple of books to read at a time,

```
from bookshelf import book1, book5, bookN
```

The thing to note in either cases is that the entire bookshelf is still occupying space in your study, regardless of how you go about reading the books. In the python world, what this means is that regardless of whether you import the entire package, or just import a select few modules into your namespace, the entire module has to be imported and kept in memory.